# Index was outside the bounds of the array. VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

[My problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hIDqG.jpg)

Index was outside the bounds of the array. when i try to run the code , it generates this error
i have two forms : SIGN IN and SIGN UP , my problem is they don't work together and generates the error attached below

```vb
Dim fs As New FileStream("C:\Users\Selmen\Desktop\vb\logs.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite)
        Dim sr As New StreamReader(fs)
        Dim sw As New StreamWriter(fs)
        Dim s As String
        Dim t() As String
        Dim trouve As Integer = 0
        Dim tt() As String
        Dim ch As String
        ch = TextBox1.Text + "#" + TextBox2.Text + "#" + TextBox3.Text + "#" + TextBox4.Text + "#" + TextBox5.Text
        tt = ch.Split("#")
        Do While (trouve = 0) And (sr.Peek > -1)
            s = sr.ReadLine
            t = s.Split("#")
            If String.Compare(t(2), tt(2)) = 0 Then
                trouve = 1
            End If
        Loop
        If (trouve = 1) Then
            MsgBox("user existant")
        Else

            sw.WriteLine(ch)

            Me.Hide()
            Form4.Show()

        End If
        sw.Close()
        sr.Close()

        fs.Close()

    End Sub
```

If String.Compare(t(2), tt(2)) = 0 Then I get:

> IndexOutOfRangeException was unhandled / Index was outside the bounds of the array.

Comment: You need to check that the array `t` has enough elements to access `t(2)`, so use something like `If t.Length >=3 AndAlso String.Compare(t(2), tt(2)) = 0 Then`.

Comment: First, now and forever turn on Option Strict. Project Properties -> Compile tab. Also for future projects Tools -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> VB Defaults

Answer (score -1):

Streams need to be disposed. Instead of using streams you can easily access a text file with the .net `File` class.

`File.ReadAllLines` returns an array of lines in the file. We can loop through the lines in a For Each. The lower case `c` following the `"#"` tells the compiler that you intend a `Char` not a `String`. `String.Split` expects a `Char`. Normally, `String.Compare` is used to order strings in alphabetical order. You just need an `=`. As soon as we find a match we exit the loop with `Exit For`.

We don't actually need the array of the text boxes `Text` property unless there is no match. Putting the elements in braces intializes and fills the array of String.

`File.AppendAllLines` does what it says. It is expecting an array of strings. As with the text boxes, we put our line to append in braces.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim p = "path to file"
    Dim lines = File.ReadAllLines(p)
    Dim trouve As Integer
    For Each line In lines
        Dim thirdField = line.Split("#"c)(2)
        If thirdField = TextBox3.Text Then
            trouve = 1
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    If trouve = 1 Then
        MsgBox("user existant")
    Else
        Dim tt = {TextBox1.Text, TextBox2.Text, TextBox3.Text, TextBox4.Text, TextBox5.Text}
        File.AppendAllLines(p, {String.Join("#", tt)})
        Me.Hid3e()
        Form4.Show()
    End If
End Sub
```